# update Master page label with username without pulling from session

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, master-pages

On my site I display a logged in username on the master page (in a label) this is done as below, by pulling the username from the session object and putting it into the label on the master page, page_init page event.  My problem is that I am bypassing the session now because of timeout issues i wont bore you all with but now I need to change the code to pop the username into the master page label once, then not try and access the session again as it clears after around 10 minutes due to the IIS pool.  I realise i could open a new connection to the database each time the master page loaded to retrieve the user name but I thought there might be an easier way than that.  any help would be really appreciated.
       
      
     `Protected Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init

            txtUserInfo.Text = (Session("name") & " [ " & Session("org") & " ]")
      End Sub`

Comment: Can you not use `User.Identity.Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the user name alone Humpy's reply would suffice (assuming the thread principal/identity is populated correctly). If you need more bits of information you could use cookies:

After login, set the cookie with a reasonable expiration:

```
Response.Cookies["userInfo"]["name"] = "currentUsername";   
Response.Cookies["userInfo"]["org"] = "currentOrg";   
Response.Cookies["userInfo"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
```

On subsequent requests you can pull the data out of the cookie:

```
if(Request.Cookies["userInfo"] != null)
{
   HttpCookie c = Request.Cookies["userInfo"];
   txtUserInfo.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(c["name"]) & " [" & Server.HtmlEncode(c["org"]) & "]";
}
```

See here for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.ASPX

Comment: Thanks Matk, this appears to be what i need but am coding in VB.  Not sure how to change your code as it seams to be c#  Sorry.  Also sorry all for not being more specific about the "org" data i also need, i didnt think this was relevant as i didn't know about the user.Identify.name function. :)

Comment: sorry, ignore me.  followed link and has example code so I will implament and mark as answer later this evening.  Thanks all. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use..

```
txtUserInfo.Text = User.Identity.Name;
```

This is how I use mine. Once the user logs in, displays the user's names perfectly. Hope this helps!